# javaFX - resizing TextArea/other UI controls with main application window

Tags: java, layout, javafx, resize

In my JavaFX application I need to update it to handle window resizing. What I want to do is for when the window gets bigger keep everything aligned the same and just have the TextArea grow to be proportionate with the window and similar when making it smaller.

I will set a min and max height to fit the buttons on the right-hand side (decreasing the spacing a little as it gets smaller).

I'm figuring out that an AnchorPane is not the best option for this and I was hoping I could get a little guidance on a better approach. The text area I am using is custom, extending StyledTextArea (RichTextFX API).

Last spec is I want the text field and button under the text to be aligned with the text area and I think the Pane to make distance between the TextField and button will be a cumbersome approach (I was planning on not making it resizable).

Image for reference : [text app image](http://s22.postimg.org/fgopi6781/textapp.png)

Any help would be really appreciated. If it makes a difference, this entire layout is inside a BorderPane center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?scenebuilder-stylesheet ../application.css?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="leftPane" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="582.0" prefWidth="855.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.TextProController">
  <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
  <children>
    <VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="649.0" layoutY="0.0" prefHeight="582.0" prefWidth="205.0" spacing="55.0" styleClass="right-split">
      <children>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleLoadText" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Load Text">
          <font>
            <Font size="14.0" fx:id="x1" />
          </font>
        </Button>
        <Button font="$x1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleFleschIndex" prefWidth="160.0" text="Flesch Index" />
        <Button font="$x1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleEditDistance" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Edit Distance" />
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleMarkovText" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Generate Markov Text">
          <font>
            <Font size="13.5" />
          </font>
        </Button>
        <CheckBox fx:id="spellingBox" font="$x1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSpelling" text="Spelling Suggestions" />
        <CheckBox fx:id="autocompleteBox" font="$x1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAutoComplete" text="AutoComplete" />
      </children>
      <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="5.0" />
      </padding>
    </VBox>
    <AnchorPane layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="582.0" prefWidth="650.0" styleClass="left-split">
      <children>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="0.0" layoutY="525.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="642.0" spacing="15.0">
          <children>
            <TextField fx:id="fleschField" prefWidth="72.0" />
            <Label text="Flesch Index">
              <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
              </font>
            </Label>
            <Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="322.0" />
            <Button font="$x1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClear" text="Clear" />
          </children>
          <padding>
            <Insets left="39.0" />
          </padding>
        </HBox>
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;





    public class MainApp extends Application {
        private Stage primaryStage;
        private BorderPane rootLayout;

        private LaunchClass launch;
        spelling.WordPath wp;
        textgen.MarkovTextGenerator mtg;



        // called at start of application
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

            this.primaryStage.setTitle("TextProApp");
            //primaryStage.setResizable(false);

            try {
                // Load root layout from fxml
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
                rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
                Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            launch = new LaunchClass();

            showTextProApp();
        }

        /**
         * Shows the main TextApplication scene
         */
        public void showTextProApp() {
            try {
                // Load the fxml file and set into the center of the main layout
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view/TextAppLayout.fxml"));

                AnchorPane textProPage = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
                rootLayout.setCenter(textProPage);

                // Connect controller and main app
                TextProController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.setMainApp(this);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Exception gets thrown if the fxml file could not be loaded
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TextProController {

    private MainApp mainApp;

    // UI Controls
    private AutoSpellingTextArea textBox;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane leftPane;

    @FXML
    private TextField fleschField;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox autocompleteBox;

    @FXML 
    private CheckBox spellingBox;

    @FXML
    private VBox rightBox;



     /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // make field displaying flesch score read-only
        fleschField.setEditable(false);

        // instantiate and add custom text area
        textBox = new AutoSpellingTextArea();
        textBox.setPrefSize(570, 492);
        textBox.setWrapText(true);
        textBox.setLayoutX(40);
        textBox.setLayoutY(25); 
        leftPane.getChildren().add(textBox);


    }




    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     * Also give reference to AutoSpellingTextArea
     * 
     * 
     * @param mainApp
     */
    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
        textBox.setMainApp(mainApp);
        textBox.setReferences();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your whole java class.,this can be done with listeners. afaik

Comment: updated to show relevant code in classes. I figured I'd have to use listeners, but I thought it also may be necessary/more efficient if I used some different containers in places

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I understood your problem, if you want to resize your `Pane` you may use the `hgrow` property which controls the horizontal grow along with the `AnchorPane.left/rightAnchor` which fixes the left/right side of your `Pane` to the parent`s at the desired distance. Try this basic Layout. You can adapt it to your code.

```
<HBox maxHeight="1080.0" maxWidth="1980.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
 <children>
  <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="402.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
     <children>
        <TextArea prefHeight="341.0" prefWidth="368.0" />
        <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
     </children>
  </VBox>
  <VBox layoutX="402.0" maxWidth="200.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
     <children>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="Button">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets left="50.0" top="50.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </Button>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="Button">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets left="50.0" top="50.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </Button>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="Button">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets left="50.0" top="50.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </Button>
     </children>
  </VBox>
 </children>
</HBox>
```